# How do you add new constructor values for a derived class?

Tags: python

I am following an example due to being new at Python, to get a simple TCP connection. The following code is the server portion, but I would like to add my own constructor that accepts other values, such as a name and possibly ID.

The server is as follows :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import SocketServer


class MyTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True

class MyTCPServerHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        while 1:
            try:
                data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()

            except Exception, e:
                print "Error getting message. ", e

            if data:
                print data




server = MyTCPServer(('192.168.1.103', 13373), MyTCPServerHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

The client code is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import json

hostname = '192.168.1.103'
port = 13373

try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((hostname,port))

except Exception, e:
    print "Error, could not open socket: ", e

sock.send("HI")
```

In my server, I tried to add a `def __init__(self, name, id)` but that didn't seem to work. When I create a new server

```
server = MyTCPServer(('192.168.1.103', 13373), MyTCPServerHandler)
```

I'd like to pass in also, a name, and ID.

Reading the documentation for SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer it says that

```
__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass)
(Constructor)


Constructor. May be extended, do not override.
```

Comment: What's wrong with overriding the initializer?

Comment: @user791953 I usually work with twisted, however it looks like a class coding issue, before give you an answer, why you don't try to create your own constructor and call from parent constructor into your own constructor

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams if I override the initializer, the arguments that are expected changes and errors out. I tried to make a blank initializer, but then it will complain about passing it 3 arguments (the tuple, and handler) instead of however many the __init__ asks for.

Comment: You have to adhere to [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), but there is nothing that prevents you from overriding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its helps you  to understand the concept

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "entering A"
        super(A, self).__init__()
        print "leaving A"

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "entering B"
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print "leaving B"

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        print "entering c"
        A.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self)
        print "leaving c"
```

Comment: I think what I need to do is override the constructor, but according to this http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/SocketServer.TCPServer-class.html#__init__

I may not be allowed to?